# How to write an Integration test for API with Message Queue?

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, nsq

Consider that I have an API end-point http://localhost/add-page-view. When we send a post request with data `{url: "google.com"}` it will be sent to a message queue, then later will be inserted to the DB by the queue subscriber

I need to write a test case that will send a post request to this end-point, then check whether `"google.com"` has been inserted to DB. Since it's inserted via Message Queue, we aren't sure whether it's inserted or not.

One way is to post data to end-point after 2 seconds check whether it has been inserted

But, that doesn't sound like a good solution

Note: It's an integration test, not a unit test

Comment: You can poll DB for new value

Comment: @Alderven but it creates unnecessary DB calls. I was looking for a more sufficient method